# Flutter strange padding on top of status bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove the strange padding on top of the status bar. I am simply using an image and want to put that image on top of the screen that is behind the status bar. So that the status bar icons should be overlayed on the image.

Simply using **Scaffold** as a parent widget and then simple an Image. Screen shot is here!

The icons are not properly overlapping the image, and there is a white padding on top head!

I am using an Android Emulator right now, can somebody please figure out what I am missing.

```
class PreSignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final PreSignInController controller = Get.put(PreSignInController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            getRedCarBox(context),
          ]
      );
    )
}
```

Thanks & Advance

Comment: you want to display this icons over on image and remove top padding(top white space)? please try to add your code snippet, if its possible

Comment: can you please provide a code

Comment: Code provided that I am using!

Comment: @JunaidHassan, remove first `SizedBox()` widget

Comment: @Ravindra thanks I forgot to remove that ;) hats off to you!

Comment: @JunaidHassan, refer my below answer also hope its help to you, if your problem has been solved so accept and upvote my answer, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code, I have tried

```
- Scaffold
     - Column
          - Container
               - Image
```

Your Widget:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/27/11/23/cat-7094808__340.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Add your other widgets here
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Or Using **`SafeArea`**, `top` property `false`

```
  SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Container(),
    ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          bottom: false,
          child: _buildBody(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          bottom: false,
          child: _yourBody(),
        ),
```

Why to use SafeArea :

SafeArea class Null safety. A widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system. For example, this will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen.